# Julia: Generate code at runtime and store it for future evaluation/execution

Tags: serialization, reflection, julia, metaprogramming, code-generation

In Julia, how one can generate arbitrary code to serialize it into a file for future execution under completely different program instance? Is it even possible? Is there a need to store any current context for future execution?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for PackageCompiler.jl (https://github.com/JuliaLang/PackageCompiler.jl)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more detailed answer

1. Put your code in a Julia package. This is something you should do with any production code - it is so much more convenient. Let say it is `MyPackage`
2. Create a script that runs all methods in the package with types that you plan to use so the compiler knows which version of those methods to compile. Let us call it `precompile_MyPackage.jl`. You could use commands/scenarios that you use regularly plus perhaps test sets from `MyPackage`.
3. Compile the package using `PackageCompiler`

```
using PackageCompiler
create_sysimage(:MyPackage, sysimage_path="sys_MyPackage.so", precompile_execution_file="precompile_MyPackage.jl")
```

4. Once done you will be starting Julia with the following comand:

```
julia --sysimage sys_MyPackage.so
```

Finally, please have a look at the excellent tutorial video https://live.juliacon.org/talk/Z8TE39